# Web Application Organization/Structure?

Tags: asp.net

I've used MVC before and really like the way it is organized but at times I have to go back to working on ASP.net Webform applications and really wonder what the best way to organize the code is.

Does anyone know of resources that deal with just that? I am pretty familiar with C# but would like to gain further insight.

An example would be a news article portion of a website. 
You'd have a web form to display the data to users and then one for administrators to post the articles. Do you simply do everything in the code behind or do you farm it out to another controller-like class you've created?

Comment: I'd heard that it is best to separate the concepts of data, markup, and ui control like MVC does but I haven't been able to find a way to effectively do that.

Answer (score 0):

Break the logical components into separate modules, which *could* mean separate namespaces; so you might end up with separate assemblies as well.

You cannot code everything into the code-behind; especially if you are doing a large project. All you need to do is to decide on the data exchange contract between modules, or layers. You should clearly specify the module1 guy that you will need a method `Foo(param1, param2, param2):bool`, and you expect it to translate news into another language.